# Shorting the TX1+ and TX2+, RX1+ and RX2+, TX1- and TX2-, RX1- and RX2- in USB C

Tags: usb-c

I am working on a project where I need to send I2C or, Analog Data between two PCBs (main PCB and Sensor PCB) using the TX and RX pins of the USBC conntector. The main PCB has a battery charger which will take input voltage from the same USBC connector. I am not willing to use additional polarity checking IC with the USBC port. For the I2C and Analog signals I am planning to use the free pins that is TX and RX. To support the polarity manually, I would like to connect (short) the RX1+ with the RX2+, TX1+ with the TX2+, RX1- and RX2-, TX1- with TX2- on the PCB. So that even though the user flip the USB C cable, the connection will remain the same.

Please see the below image where the shorted connection is highlighted using the same color.

[image]

My question is, will there be a problem if I connect this port of the main PCB using an USB type C to type C cord with the computer or other devices for charging?